# Move Job Title and Year To Line Above In moderncv

Tags: moderncv, cv

I am using the banking style for moderncv. Is there a way I can modify the `\cventry` command so that the Employer, Job Title, City, and Year fields all appear on the same line? Something looking like this:

> **Employer**, *Job Title* ... **City** *Year*

instead of this:

> **Employer** ... **City**
>
> *Job Title* ... *Year*

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{banking}
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\nopagenumbers{}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\cventry{Date}{Job Title}{Employer}{City}{}{Description}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You could always just make a new command like `\mycventry`: `\newcommand{\mycventry}[6]{<formatting stuff>}`....

Comment: @jon Yes I was wondering if there is a simpler way to do his as I am not a latex master ;)

Comment: You mean: `\newcommand{\mycventry}[6]{\textbf{#3}, \emph{#2} ... \textbf{#4} \emph{#1}}`, and then writing `\mycventry{Date}{Job Title}{Employer}{City}{}{Description}`..?  Hard to suggest more based on your currently stated desired output.

Comment: @jon The `...` here is not an ellipsis but rather indicates that the second half is right-aligned (arbitrary space in the middle). Ideally this would also have exactly the same functionality as `\cventry` just with this new and more compact format. Not knowing the complexities behind this I wouldn't know exactly what that entails but I assume it's more complicated than `\textbf` and `\emph`, though perhaps I am wrong.

Comment: To push things to the right-hand margin, a simple `\hfill` is often enough. However, things get complicated when the total line *text* is longer than the length of the line. (I.e., put `\hfill` where I had written `...`.)

Comment: Is there any news here?

Comment: @Johannes_B I added an answer based on the comments. Feel free to correct it as necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the suggestions in the comments I eventually ended up creating this command:

```
\newcommand{\myentry}[5]{\textbf{#3}\ifthenelse{\isempty{#2}}{}{: \textit{#2}}%
  \hfill\textit{\ifthenelse{\isempty{#4}}{}{#4 | }#1}%
  \ifthenelse{\isempty{#5}}{\par\vspace{1ex}}{\\#5\par\vspace{1ex}}%
}
```

Which results in a slightly modified version of the original question (I think it looks better than what I originally wished to do).

For a command that exactly mimics my original question this can be used:

```
\newcommand{\myentry}[5]{\textbf{#3}\ifthenelse{\isempty{#2}}{}{, \textit{#2}}%
  \hfill\ifthenelse{\isempty{#4}}{}{\textbf{#4} }\textit{#1}%
  \ifthenelse{\isempty{#5}}{\par\vspace{1ex}}{\\#5\par\vspace{1ex}}%
}
```

Note that this requires the `xifthen` package and for simplification purposes I got rid of a field so this only takes 5 parameters.